# Digital download link with php

Tags: php, url, download

I use this function to make Digital download link . test.zip send my browser but file size unknown and when i download it and open show this error : "the archive is either is unknown format or damaged"
test.zip inside file folder and download.php Inside root.

```
<?php

/* Tutorial by AwesomePHP.com -> www.AwesomePHP.com */
/* Function: download with resume/speed/stream options */

/*
    Parametrs: downloadFile(File Location, File Name,
    max speed, is streaming  
    If streaming - movies will show as movies, images as images
    instead of download prompt
*/

function downloadFile($fileLocation,$fileName,$maxSpeed = 13,$doStream =
false){
    if (connection_status()!=0) return(false);
    $array = explode('.',$fileName);
$extension = strtolower(end($array));

    /* List of File Types */
    $fileTypes['swf'] = 'application/x-shockwave-flash';
    $fileTypes['pdf'] = 'application/pdf';
    $fileTypes['exe'] = 'application/octet-stream';
    $fileTypes['zip'] = 'application/zip';
    $fileTypes['doc'] = 'application/msword';
    $fileTypes['xls'] = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
    $fileTypes['ppt'] = 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint';
    $fileTypes['gif'] = 'image/gif';
    $fileTypes['png'] = 'image/png';
    $fileTypes['jpeg'] = 'image/jpg';
    $fileTypes['jpg'] = 'image/jpg';
    $fileTypes['rar'] = 'application/rar';    

    $fileTypes['ra'] = 'audio/x-pn-realaudio';
    $fileTypes['ram'] = 'audio/x-pn-realaudio';
    $fileTypes['ogg'] = 'audio/x-pn-realaudio';

    $fileTypes['wav'] = 'video/x-msvideo';
    $fileTypes['wmv'] = 'video/x-msvideo';
    $fileTypes['avi'] = 'video/x-msvideo';
    $fileTypes['asf'] = 'video/x-msvideo';
    $fileTypes['divx'] = 'video/x-msvideo';

    $fileTypes['mp3'] = 'audio/mpeg';
    $fileTypes['mp4'] = 'audio/mpeg';
    $fileTypes['mpeg'] = 'video/mpeg';
    $fileTypes['mpg'] = 'video/mpeg';
    $fileTypes['mpe'] = 'video/mpeg';
    $fileTypes['mov'] = 'video/quicktime';
    $fileTypes['swf'] = 'video/quicktime';
    $fileTypes['3gp'] = 'video/quicktime';
    $fileTypes['m4a'] = 'video/quicktime';
    $fileTypes['aac'] = 'video/quicktime';
    $fileTypes['m3u'] = 'video/quicktime';

    $contentType = $fileTypes[$extension];


    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");
    header("Content-Type: $contentType");

    $contentDisposition = 'attachment';

    if($doStream == true){
        /* extensions to stream */
        $array_listen = array('mp3','m3u','m4a','mid','ogg','ra','ram','wm',
        'wav','wma','aac','3gp','avi','mov','mp4','mpeg','mpg','swf','wmv','divx','asf');
        if(in_array($extension,$array_listen)){ 
            $contentDisposition = 'inline';
        }
    }

    if (strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "MSIE")) {
        $fileName= preg_replace('/\./', '%2e', $fileName,
substr_count($fileName, '.') - 1);
        header("Content-Disposition: $contentDisposition; filename=".$fileName);
    } else {
        header("Content-Disposition: $contentDisposition; filename=".$fileName);
    }

    header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");   
    $range = 0;
    $size = filesize($fileLocation);

    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
        list($a, $range)=explode("=",$_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']);
        str_replace($range, "-", $range);
        $size2=$size-1;
        $new_length=$size-$range;
        header("HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content");
        header("Content-Length: $new_length");
        header("Content-Range: bytes $range$size2/$size");
    } else {
        $size2=$size-1;
        header("Content-Range: bytes 0-$size2/$size");
        header("Content-Length: ".$size);
    }

    if ($size == 0 ) { die('Zero byte file! Aborting download');}
    set_magic_quotes_runtime(0); 
    $fp=fopen("$fileLocation","rb");

    fseek($fp,$range);

    while(!feof($fp) and (connection_status()==0))
    {
        set_time_limit(0);
        print(fread($fp,1024*$maxSpeed));
        flush();
        ob_flush();
        sleep(1);
    }
    fclose($fp);

    return((connection_status()==0) and !connection_aborted());
} 

/* Implementation */

downloadFile('file/','test.zip',900,false); 

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the function and I solve these issues:

1.

```
$fileLocation = $fileLocation . $fileName;
```

`$fileLocation` used to read file, but it's only contained folder name!

2.

```
$range = str_replace($range, "-", $range);
```

`str_replace` replaces "-" character, but didn't update `$range`

3.

`set_magic_quotes_runtime` is deprecated, add a check before calling that function!

You can download new code from my [github](https://github.com/PouyaDarabi/PHP/blob/master/download.php) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `?>` at the end of the file.

If that doesn't work post the zipfile somewhere where I can see it.

Comment: The file worked fine. I did a zip test and it said all was well. I also checked the zipfile inside there and it was fine too.